# Android RelativeLayout cause its children cover each other

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a listview, each item is a relativelayout which has several textviews in a line,but if one of those textview whose text is too long,this will cause the textview behind it to be covered,so I want to make it gone.But I can't know each item's width in listview and can't know each textview in relativelayout,I saw android api support a measure method,but it's so unefficient,because if I measure each widget,the system will do the same thing after me.Please supply a good method to slove my question,thanks.

@Muhannad A.Alhariri This is my solution:

```
  @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
int sumChildWidth = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);
    if (child != null) {
    if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE
        && child.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE) {
        sumChildWidth += child.getWidth();
    }
    }
}
int myWidth = Math.round(getWidth()
    - getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 15);

if (sumChildWidth > myWidth) {
    if (getChildCount() > 0 && getChildCount() - 1 >= 0) {
    View lastChild = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
    if (lastChild != null) {
        lastChild.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a `LinearLayout` for your `TextView`s and consider a maximum width(threshold) for a `TextView`

Comment: Start by editing the question to be more specific: add the problematic layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the RelativeLayout properties like

```
toRightOf and toLeftOf
```

Comment: but those textviews behind the long text will be crowed out of the relativelayout

Comment: @KrystalJake Why not using maxWidth and maxHeight? or you can use LinearLayout with gravity instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: I found I must override the RelativeLayout,then I judge its children total width,if total width is larger than RelativeLayout's width,I dismiss some its children

Comment: @KrystalJake if you found your solution helpfull don't forget to share here because we want to know how to solve the problem :)

Comment: @KrystalJake Great :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the length of That odd textview is too long because you are not using Ellipsis. Use ellipsis in textview

android:ellipsize="end"

That's the right way to do it no layout will fix your problem.